# .Net: better equiv for " " (space character)?

Tags: .net

I am using a string builder as part of a logging process. my seperator character I am using is " ". How can I output this char in a more effective way than simply " ".

For example:

```
sb.Append(" ");
```

Or this this the acceptable way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're worried that it's going to create a new string object each time, stop worrying. The compiler will optimize it to use the same string object on every call.

Answer (score 6):

If it is a single character better use `sb.Append(' ');`

Comment: Why is this better?  See Mark Byers' answer regarding compiler optimisation

Comment: @Rob Cowell: This has nothing to do with compiler optimization. The `Append(char)` overload doesn't have to check for a null argument or for the parameter length (always 1).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably thinking there is an alternative like `string.Empty` for `""`. But there is no such thing, so using `" "` is ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine.

However, you may want to raise the abstraction level a bit:

```
public static StringBuilder AppendWithSeparator(this StringBuilder sb, string value)
{
    sb.Append(value);
    sb.Append(" ");

    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be better having a `const char seperator = ' '` defined somewhere.  Then using `sb.Append(seperator)`

That would make the code more maintainable if at a later point you decide to use (eg) comma seperation.